# Django passing multiple values to html page

Tags: django

In my html page I want to display latest jobs and popular jobs. In latest jobs I'm filtered based on posted date. Actually what I want means to display popular jobs also these can be filter by count depends on job title. Is this possible to passing multiple values to html page. Give me some idea

```
views.py  
def home(request):
    now=datetime.now()
    d=datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day)
    d1= d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    latest = jobs.objects.filter(postdate__lte=d1).order_by('-postdate')
    return render_to_response('registration/home.html', {'latest': latest})


Can I use like this
return render_to_response('registration/home.html', {'latest': latest},{'popular':popular})
```

Answer (score 1):

The context is a single dictionary:

```
render_to_response('registration/home.html', {'latest': latest, 'popular': popular})
```

This is really basic Python. You should do a tutorial.